# views in jsp using spring mvc 3.0

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.0 and I have part of code given below:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewAllEmployee")
public ModelAndView getAllEmployee()
{
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("showEmployee");
    List<Employee> employee= employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
    mav.addObject("RESULT_EMPLOYEE", employee);
    return mav;
}
```

Now,  My problem is that suppose the result given by above code is 20, so, I want the result to be displayed 5 at a time in JSP so, that when user clicks next, next 5 result is displayed. How can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use displaytag, please take a look here: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/

With this element you can show your lists in your jsp pages, perform pagination, ordering, exporting, etc.

Comment: Can you provide some examples for it as it could be easy to learn??

Comment: i'm sorry i have no time to provide an example by myself, but i think you will find useful the tutorial from the website